# Permanent add Geoserver Server on Geoexplorer different URL

Tags: geoserver, geoexplorer

I have my Geoexplorer run on Open shift (asume http://geoexplorer-aaa-rhcloud.com) using this Git (https://github.com/jason-callaway/geoexplorer-on-openshift). My geoexplorer run perfectly,

Problem is my geoserver are on another gear on openshift (asume http://geoserver-aaa-rhcloud.com/web). I have Github File for making Geoexplorer.war (https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/tree/r4.1/geoexplorer)  and I know where should I put my new "Edited" Geoexplorer.war on 1st Git to push on open shift.

My question is how to make my geoexplorer permanently add my geoserver url, at which part of the Git source I should add / edit so that I dont have to repeat step "Add New Server" each time I open / reload my geoexplorer site?

Answer (score 1):

Already solved, Just edit and add new geoserver url in :

> ../suite/geoexplorer/app/template/composer.html

add this custom geoserver :

```
> customserver: {
                    url: "http://yourcustomdomain/geoservernotinroot/wms",
                    title: "yourservername"
                },
```

*Dont forget to set Declared SRS in each your geoserver layer to "**EPSG:102113**" and compute data, otherwise **geoexplorer will not show your layer**!!

commit master, build using *mvn install*, replace ROOT.war and push to openshift.
DONE!

Comment: Thanks for answering your question - this will be useful to someone in the future. After a day or so you'll have the option to mark this as the accepted answer - this is the way to close the question off, rather than adding "solved" to the title.